# How to make a jWindow appear below a textfield when my textfield is in another class?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I want to make an autocomplete program (just like when you search in the Google). When you start to type in the textfield, a list of suggestions appear below. Its hard for me to download swingX in the net thats why I come up for this option to use a JWindow.

Is it possible to have this option?

Thanks...

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [Is it possible to have an autocomplete using jtextfield and a Jlist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist)

Comment: java.net DNS has been down (and with it all project areas, including SwingX) - current status (via @sonyabarry, the community manager) Java.net update - "DNS has been updated, but it will take up to 48 hours for cache to expire worldwide. Some have access now".

Comment: Mikel (no offense meant, just caring) - looks to me you start building the house in 5nd floor ;-) It's not trivial to get auto-complete correct, without a halfway sound knowledge of Swing it'll be a path of pain

Comment: @kleopatra - yeah, your right. Now i feel my head is going to explode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.getLocationOnScreen()` to identify the location of your text field in absolute screen coordinates. Then calculate the location where to put your JWindow.

Comment: Do you have a sample for that? Because it was just suggested to me to use JWindow and I'm very much new for that stuff in java.