# Embed a JComboBox inside a JRadioButtonMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, menu, jcombobox, jradiobutton

I want to put a JComboBox inside a JRadioButtonMenuItem in a popup menu, is it possible ? 
How can it be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: And what's driving this requirement?

Comment: I want to have an item in the PupUp menu with multi values selectable without opening another menu, directly inside the JComboBox.

Comment: I want a chicken, stuffed inside a turkey, deep fried in chocolate!   ( Sorry, your question just reminded me so much of the mayor in "Cloudy, With A Chance Of Meatballs". ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible directly because there is still one [Java bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511560/714968), simple Swing doesn't allowed two Popup's windows in once time, maybe [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127463/714968) could be acceptable,