# Open JPopupMenu from opened JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jpopupmenu, jpopup

I'd like to change OOTB behaviour of combobox, to *freeze* it after right mouse button click (detecting which button was clicked is easy, so that's not the point) and open JPopupMenu istead of choosing that entry.

So - how to disable choosing entry on given condition and use custom behaviour then?

I tried to start by adding mouse listeners to all combobox components, but without success - nothing changed

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        final String labels[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selecting JComboBox");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(labels);
        frame.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (Component c : comboBox.getComponents()) {
            c.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("cli");
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("pre");
                    super.mousePressed(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve when a value is selected in the combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in Swing is not possible to showing two lightweight popup containers in the same moment
- example about [JComboBox popup from JPopup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511560/714968)
- there are dirty hack about set `JPopup` to heavyweight
- but I'd suggest to mixing `AWT Container` with `Swing JComponents` and to use `AWT.Popup` with `Swing.JComponent` (`JMenuItem` or `JButton`)

Comment: +1 I've been playing around and yes you're right definitely bot possible!