# Find owner of combobox popup

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox, jpopup

I have a popup with settings displayed to the user. If you click outside it, its hidden but if you click inside it remains visible.

The event handler handling this behavior gets the `Component` (that was clicked) and by using `component.getParent()` recursively I can check if its a child of my settings panel. This has worked so far.

But I just added a `JComboBox` to that panel and it turns out that the "selectable items popup" (does it have a name?) the combobox shows when clicked isnt a child of the combobox. Attempting to select something in a combobox would hide my settings panel.

Using the NetBeans debugger I can see its of the type `BasicComboPopup$1` (is that an anonymous class?), but it isn't an instance of neither `ComboPopup`, `JPopupMenu` nor `BasicComboPopup`.

I need a way to identify the owner/parent combobox of the "combobox popup" that was clicked.

Comment: Yes, that is an anonymous class. Also, a wild guess, the popup parent will be the combobox popup so it can be drawn inside it.

Comment: could be good question, can you please post an SSCCE demonstrated your Components hierarchy.

Comment: @SJuan76 the parent is a `JViewport`.

Comment: @mizipzor parent is JViewport, not (event I use that) don't use JViewport, this isn't Component and Container too, use JLayer, basic stuff is GlassPane, but carrefully with lightweight status for JViewport and GlassPane

Comment: curious: how do you keep open two popupMenus (the settings and the combo popup)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not entirely sure, but you might be looking for

```java
 popup.getInvoker();
```

which would return the invoking comboBox.

Below's utility method (copied from SwingXUtilities, which comes with the SwingX framework): given you found the source component (unfortunate naming in the method is focusOwner ;-) of an event, it checks whether that source is somehwhere below the parent, including popups.

Just noticed that your parent is-a popup, so you have to adjust the logic a bit, switching the first and second if block (didn't try, though - it's unusual to have more than one visible popups. :-)

```java
/**
 * Returns whether the component is part of the parent's
 * container hierarchy. If a parent in the chain is of type 
 * JPopupMenu, the parent chain of its invoker is walked.
 * 
 * @param focusOwner
 * @param parent
 * @return true if the component is contained under the parent's 
 *    hierarchy, coping with JPopupMenus.
 */
public static boolean isDescendingFrom(Component focusOwner, Component parent) {
    while (focusOwner !=  null) {
        if (focusOwner instanceof JPopupMenu) {
            focusOwner = ((JPopupMenu) focusOwner).getInvoker();
            if (focusOwner == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (focusOwner == parent) {
            return true;
        }
        focusOwner = focusOwner.getParent();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although the clicked component wasn't a `JPopupMenu`, walking its parents recursively (like your code does) I found one. Then its `getInvoker()`'s parents had the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

1. not sure if you talking about

   - `mouse` event
   - `keyboard` event
   - `mouse` and `keyboard` event
2. have look at [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) there are methods for `child` v.s. `parent` and vice versa
3. post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), with detailed descriptions about desired events, becaue there a few ways how to extraxt and modify the `Popup` from `JComboBox`

EDIT

in the case that you use `AWT Popup` or mixing `Swing lightweight` with `AWT heavyweight` components, then you have to look at [Swing Utils by Darryl](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/)

Comment: Its a custom event. We do a lot of custom drawing so we have created a `MousePressListener` which has the method `void mousePressed(Component c)` which is the one I'm implementing to create the behavior.

Comment: did you `1)` replace popup with your own, maybe then there are couple of side effecta, all custom popup (my view) are based on J/Window or undecorated Swing JDialog), `2)`  or extract, modify and add returns back to JComboBox, `3)` maybe someone created that similair way as your, have got the same issue, have to wait

Comment: have to check [BugParade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245982/open-jpopupmenu-from-opened-jcombobox/11246209#11246209)

Comment: I'm trying to extract a SSCCE, but its hard when we've added so much custom event handling. Would have been easier if we stuck to the built in stuff.

Comment: *"custom event handling"*  (Shudder)  What is the odds that if you were able to remove that code, the problem would vanish?

Comment: @AndrewThompson thats my current approach, get rid of the mouse event handler class, use the builtin stuff, if it still fails at least I will be able to provide a SSCCE.