# Java with multiple JPopup

Tags: java, swing, mouse, jpopup

I am trying to build some very basic interactive GUI for a chess-game. The idea is to help players by allowing them to get "help" by allowing them  to click on each chess-piece and see suggestions about what moves to make and such. The only requirement I have is that I after a player has clicked (right-clicked with a mouse) on the chess piece, that a popup appears on both sides of the piece. The left piece contains some information about the piece, the right piece what moves to make.

As far as I can work out, in order to do that I must use JPopUpmenu as I can use the show method which accepts x and y coordinates as input. However, I am not able to use two jpopups it seems. Is there a way around this or is there an alternative way to accomplish the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- not possible to `show()` more than one [JPopup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html), [maybe bug maybe decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245982/open-jpopupmenu-from-opened-jcombobox/11246209#11246209)
- could be possible by using `JWindow`, better could be un_decorated `JDialog` (`modalit`y, `setAlwaysOnTop`, `toFront`)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as far as I can work out it is not possible to "popup" these at specific x-y locations?