# Java Autocomplete TextField (Ajax style)

Tags: java, ajax, swing, autocomplete

I need to create a JTextField (or any component where I can type something) and it has to offer a list of dynamicaly populated values. When I type a new character, the propositions are updated (Like Ajax does)

One particularity is that the user can only choose a value that was populated. I need that for my users to select an existing city from a database.

What would be the easiest way to make it with Swing ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you can make use of combo box

Comment: Did you search the forum? The fact that an "autocomplete" tag exists would indicate that questions of this type have been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [JIDE Common Layer](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) for autocompletion in Java Swing.  Take a look at the [WebStart demo](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/1.4/jide_demo.jnlp).

It's free and open source, and if the provided autocompletion options don't quite match what you are trying to do I found it really easy to plug in my own logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can implements [Auto complete ComboBox / JFextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) based on standard Java API, there aren't any issues with Focus or Caret nor with performance for largiest Arrays for autocompleted [JComboBox and JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Swingx](https://swingx.java.net/).Contains extensions to the Swing GUI toolkit, including new and enhanced components that provide functionality commonly required by rich client applications. Highlights include:

Sorting, filtering, highlighting for tables, trees, and lists
Find/search
Auto-completion
Login/authentication framework
TreeTable component
Collapsible panel component
Date picker component
Tip-of-the-Day component