# MySQL autocomplete field in Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, autocomplete, intellisense

I am creating an MySQL editor using swing . Is there way to provide **intellisense** while I write my query in **JTextArea**

To clarify more-

Suppose I want to write query 'use db1;' in my JTextArea then while I write 'u' it should predict use keyword after which it should suggest all **schemas name / other possible keywords.**

Also if possible to make this then how can I come to know that there should be database name or  table name after keyword,?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a library are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: "Java" is not an acronym, so please don't capitalize it like that. A lot of us are very case sensitive.

Comment: besides when searching on stack overflow i found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893685/java-autocomplete-textfield-ajax-style