# Auto Complete Search Jtextfield Java

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

can anyone help me with this , I have a jtable and I want to search for the data in it with jtextfield , as the user types, suggestions appears in a drop down list and select from it , then the user select it and the results appears in the table.

Comment: Please add some code that you have been working on. The question doesn't provide any details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes that possible two ways

1) easiest without implement for autocomplete `JTextField`, 
 - [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) has implemented [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) code example in the tutorial

2) by implement [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968) (read whole thread because there is most excelent alternative implemented in the SwingX) and for [JTable to set Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Answer (score 1):

For the JTextField, use getText() to get the input(but you have to update that constantly). For the drop down menu, use what's called an editable combo box - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable has an explanation.