# How do I create a textfield or a combo box or any component in java that can act like an intellisense?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have an autocomplete using jtextfield and a Jlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist)

it can be a jtextfield or a combo box or a plugin or any component (or like the drop down component where the user can pick suggestions from a database). i will make a search bar like of google's that gets values from my database. Thank you :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have an autocomplete using jtextfield and a Jlist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918) OR [Auto Complete Search Jtextfield Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957828/auto-complete-search-jtextfield-java)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Glazed Lists AutoCompleteSupport.
Screencasts and sample code you can find here: [Glazed Lists Developer](http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/)

You can download jar from here: [Glazed Lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/)

Comment: the download page is not available