# JComboBox to list age

Tags: java, arrays, swing, numbers, jcombobox

Purpose: JComboBox to list down ages that a user can select

I realize that I need an array of integers. What part of the Math functions in Java will allow me to easily do that? The list of numbers will be from 1-100 in sequential order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you need the Math functions.

This would work:

```
List<Integer> age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    age.add(i);
}
JComboBox ageComboBox = new JComboBox(age.toArray());
```

Comment: Putting that in, I get an error. Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token. What does this mean?

Comment: @Maydayfluffy on which line did you get the error, maybe you're using the code incorrectly?

Comment: The problem with this code is List<int>. It should be List<Integer> . Same for ArrayList<Integer>. I edited the answer to remove the compile errors

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any math functions.  Look up JComboBox in the java docs and you'll find a `.addItem` function.  It can take a String (e.g. "1") or a Number (e.g. new Integer(1)).  Just iterate in a for-loop and add the items you need.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) using a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) would be a better component for selecting an integer based age or Y.O.B.  See [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) in the tutorial for more info.

[image: 3 spinners]

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have look at [AutoComplete ComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968)