# JTextField stops using MaskFormatter after being cleared

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I'm doing a Sudoku solver and for that I want my JTextFields to only accept one of the numbers 123456789 as valid input. Therefore I use a MaskFormatter toghether with a JFormattedTextField. However when I clear all the TextFields by doing .setText("") the MaskFormatter doesn't work anymore. After clearing the textboxes I can write anything in them again. Why and how do I fix it?

My code is basically:

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("#");
formatter.setValidCharacters("123456789");
Font textFieldFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        southPanel.setBorder(lineBorder);
        field[i][j] = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        field[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        field[i][j].setFont(textFieldFont);
        southPanel.add(field[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Then when I clear it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        field[i][j].setText("");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is all the code, haven't written most of it cuz my friend did it. I'm just now taking over to fix the GUI a little bit.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4018313/SudokuSolver.zip

Also, after some more testing it seems like after clearing all the boxes you can type a lot of charachters that should not be there but when you click on another field all of them will disappear. Then if you click in the other boxes the numbers you wrote earlier will appear.

Don't get this!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"one of the numbers 123456789 as valid input."* Use a [`JSpinner`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344708/jcombobox-to-list-age/9345991#9345991).

Comment: A JSpinner is like a drop down menu?
EDIT: Now I see what it is but there is so many (9*9 = 81) boxes so that would noot look very good :)

Comment: *"I see what it is but there is so many (9*9 = 81) boxes so that would noot look very good"* I do not understand.  Are you saying the number range is from 1 to 81?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson could you able to findout and tracing question by Jeanette on OTN, because I can't found way how to searching threads older than one year, eeeeeeerrrght

Comment: @mKorbel I'm no expert on OTN search, sorry.  Often I will use Google to search the OTN.

Comment: See also [`CellTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4151403/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you the exact reason but `setText` seems to drive your `JFormattedTextField` crazy because `""` is a String and it is against the current mask.

Please try using `setValue(null)` instead.

I've just made sure that this method works. The next piece of code proves it:

```
public class Two extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Two().a();
    }

    void a() throws Exception {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("#");
        formatter.setValidCharacters("123456789");
        final JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        JButton b = new JButton("null!");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setValue(null);
            }
        });
        this.add(field);
        this.add(b);
        this.setSize(100, 100);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

After clicking the *null!* button formatter continues to work as it is supposed to work.

Comment: not easy job setValue(null), can you do that correctly for JFormattedTextField, really this's evil, I'd have to find out nice thread on another forum

Comment: Yeah I tried to add an empty string to the valid charachters list before but I don't think it's possible since it's an empty string. Also tried you suggestion but it was the same!

Comment: @Qwe I'll update my post in this thread, please can you correct me

Comment: Found this: http://tech.chitgoks.com/2010/06/09/allow-maskformatter-to-accept-empty-value-in-java/ not sure how my teachers are gonna feel about that though :)

Comment: @mKorbel please try to run the class from my answer - it works for me without any exceptions (Java7)

Comment: Hmm, you code works for me too. So I tried to set my Reset button to just reset the upper ringht textfield field[0][0] and if I do that it works just as well as your code. So I gues it has something to to with the multiple calls taking to long or what?

Comment: Ok, so I have now found what the issue was. The Issue was that I used the same MaskFormatter for all of the textfields. I noticed that the first one always worked perfectly but not the others so I created 81 identical MaskFormatters and it works awesome now! It doesn't matter if I use "" or null.