# getting integer values from textfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to get Integer values from my jtextfield but not able to it is showing incompatible datatypes required int found string. Is there some other way of writing my code is as follows and i want to get only integer values

```
private void jTextField2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource()==jTextField2){
            int jml = jTextField3.getText();
            jTextField1.setText(numberToWord(jml));

        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Consider using a `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberNodel` instead. 2) Both `JTextField` & `JSpinner` have better listeners than `MouseListener` available - they are `ActionListener` & `ChangeListener` respectively.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344708/jcombobox-to-list-age/9345991#9345991) related to `JSpinner`.  The models make it a versatile and intuitive (for the user) component.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `Integer.parseInt(String)`

```
private void jTextField2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getSource()==jTextField2){
            int jml = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
            jTextField1.setText(numberToWord(jml));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Be sure to handle `NumberFormatException`, which `parseInt()` will throw if the use inputs something non-numeric.

Comment: Yes, it is a checked exception so it will force the user to handle it. I have left some space for OP to think over.

Comment: I think `trim()` would help here as well.

Answer (score 4):

As You're getting values from textfield as `jTextField3.getText();`.

As it is a **`textField`** it will return you string format as its [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) says:

> **`String getText()`**
>
> ```
>       Returns the text contained in this TextComponent.
> ```

So, convert your `String` to `Integer` as:

```
int jml = Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
```

instead of directly setting

```
   int jml = jTextField3.getText();
```