# Allow characters storage on JTextField only if are numbers

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield, keylistener

I want to filter the key that are pressed on `JTextField`.
I want that only numbers are allowed, and if other character are pressed it remove it or don't allow the storage on the text field.

I'm thinking to use an `addKeyListener`, and use the methods: key pressed and key released.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers

Comment: *"I want that only numbers are allowed"*  Use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel` as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9345991/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
final JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
      String oldText = "";
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                // Store old text in a temporary variable
                oldText = myTextField.getText();
      }

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                 // Make sure that the user is typing a number else replace with old text.
                 int charCode = (int)keyEvent.getKeyChar();
                 if (charCode  < 48 || charCode  > 57){
                     myTextField.setText(oldText); // Replace with old text.
                 }
      }

      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
      }
    });
```

Comment: And what if _copy - paste_ is performed?

Answer (score 1):

No offence, Mr. Ravindra's answer is correct but it fails when you type continuously .. 
I hope this helps :

```
    final JTextField myTextFiled=new JTextField();
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("onlyNums");
    KeyListener myKeyListner=new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getKeyChar()>='0' && e.getKeyChar()<='9')                  
                myTextFiled.setText(myTextFiled.getText()+e.getKeyChar());
            else if(e.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && myTextFiled.getText().length()>0)
                myTextFiled.setText(myTextFiled.getText().substring(0, myTextFiled.getText().length()-1));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        }
    };
    //to null out handling other inputs
    myTextFiled.setInputMap(JTextField.WHEN_FOCUSED, new InputMap());
    //to add your own handling
    myTextFiled.addKeyListener(myKeyListner);
```

**Note: You have to add handling to insert/remove from the pointer's position.**

Regards,

Comment: And what if _copy - paste_ is performed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `Document`:

```
public class NumericDocument extends PlainDocument {

    @Override
    public void insertString(int pos, String text, AttributeSet as)
                                               throws BadLocationException {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(text);
            super.insertString(pos, text, as);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        }
    }

}
```

Install to your `TextField`:

```
JtextField field = new JTextField();
field.setDocument(new NumericDocument());
```

This will work, even if text is pasted (where no `KeyEvent` is fired).