# ComboBox, Automatic filling. Java

Tags: java, swing, loops, combobox

I currently have a shopping cart that records how many orders have been made by using a :

`int orderNumber` and `just ++` when ever a new order is made, I want to add a edit function where someone will click on a edit button and it will open a new frame where they will select what order they want to edit via a combobox, the problem is that I need the comboBox to fill with 1,2,3 etc... Depending on how many orders were made. I had a go at achieving this with the method below however it only errors.

```
orderNumbersList = new String[orderNumber];
                for (int i = 1; i <= orderNumber; i++) {
                    orderNumbersList[i] = "" + i;
                }

             JComboBox orderNumberBox = new JComboBox(orderNumbersList);
```

Comment: Adapt the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344708/jcombobox-to-list-age to your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero based. Replace

```
for (int i = 1; i <= orderNumber; i++) {
   orderNumbersList[i] = "" + i;
}
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < orderNumber; i++) {
    orderNumbersList[i] = Integer.toString(i + 1);
}
```

Notice the assigned value `i` is adjusted

Comment: that has made it work thanks, but the problem is now though that it starts of with a order number of 0 where as obviously my order numbers start of with one .