# Getting a Swing to read input without a submit button

Tags: java, swing, submit

This is for an assignment so responses should not contain the code written for me.

I have written a program that is essentially an auto-complete program. It takes a word and returns the best matches.

I am trying to write a front end for it in swing(which I have no experience in) and want my front end to do the following: I want the input box to constantly be reading for user input, feeding that value to the other program, and returning the matches immediately in a drop down box, as, say, Google does. I can't seem to find any information on how to do this, all the intro tutorials use a submit button.

Can anyone explain to me how this would be done, or point me to a resource that could explain it? Again, please don't write the code for me, I don't want to unwittingly cheat on my assignment.

Comment: search for AutoComplete, or Decorator, but in all cases good code is wrotten, long tine ago, and don't reinvent the wheel, those code are done by great minds ...

Comment: @mKorbel, good advice, however for an assignment, some artificial restrictions may be in place, esp. if the point of the assignment is this task...

Comment: The main focus of the assignment was the back end suggest algorithm, but all code, including that of any interface I use should be my own.

Comment: +1 for showing an intent, not to cheat :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a `JTextField`, you could register a [document listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) on it.

Comment: Worth pointing to Oracle tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html

Answer (score 3):

If your input box is a JTextField, you can add a DocumentListener [(this is a good tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to capture character entries.

Comment: Author is emphasizing on 'no code'. I think example need not to be given.

Comment: The example just shows how to include a listener in the code but does not provide a direct answer to his question

Comment: -1 An `ActionEvent` will not be triggered unless the user hits the `Enter` key while focused on the input textbox.

Comment: @mre that's kind - I deserved the -1 on that one ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think that no one from answerers ..., I'm only about `Don't reinvent the wheel`

1) use `JTable` with one (or two if is about Dictionary) Column and with basic implmentation for [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) (example with filtering from `JTextField` is in the Tutorial),  `JTable` could be most complex from `JComponents` and there is everything (quite easilly) possible

2) use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918)

3) use `SwingX Decorator` with `JXList` or `JXTable`

4) if you needed redirect output to the separate window then use `JDialog / JWindow` for popup window

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

1. Attach a handler to detect a key press on the text box.
2. Grab the text from the box, and construct a "lookup" event which is runnable and submit this to some form of service which will dispatch it at some point in the future (hint: `ExecutorService`, `Future`)
3. Save this handle, and if the key press event happens again, cancel the previous and submit a new one.
4. When the event executes in the future and returns the result, popup a panel which displays the list of items.

Comment: hmmm now I understand, you are from C++  :-)

Comment: @mKorbel, haha... that obvious?!? I thought the OP was after a solution that did not use any existing stuff...