# How to use addItem() on a JComboBox without modifying the editor?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to use an editable `JComboBox` such that upon a user typing into the editor, possible results are displayed in the list part of the  combo box.

Unfortunately, I've found that upon using either `addItem(item)` or `getModel().addItem(item)`, the input typed by the user is overwritten by the first value I added. I've considered storing the editor value, adding items, and then using `setSelectedItem()` to fix this, but I wan't to preserve the state of any selected text/ caret position, and believe this should be something more trivial, but can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
JComboBox box = new JComboBox();
box.setModel(new MutableComboBoxModel());
box.setEditable(true);
box.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // Actual results are retrieved from server via HTTP
    box.addItem("Demo");
    // Here, the editor window the user was typing in is replaced with the value "Demo".. how to fix this?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968),
- for listening in [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) is there [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html),
- never use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for `Swing JComponents`, this listener is designated for `AWT Components`, for `Swing JComponents` is there [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own MutableComboBoxModel since DefaultComboBoxModel is responsible for the "add item then auto select it" behavior.