# Building a search module UI in Swing which is similar to SO tagging

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, autocomplete

I'm building on top of an existing UI which is in Swing. I need to add a search module wherein the user can enter search terms which should be auto-complete'd.

I'm considering building a UI very similar to Stackoverflow's 'tagging a question' feature. So in my use case each 'tag' would be a search term.

I'm completely new to Swing or UIs in general and have very little clue on how to start.
Any advice/pointers on how and where to start would be of great value to me.

Comment: Note that is is 'Swing' not 'Swings'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two ways

- exactly same way is implemeting [Filtering for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) (there started after 2nd or 3rd chars typed)
- of use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968)

Answer (score 1):

You should use and ArrayList where every time someone types a keyword into the search box and clicks find, the program goes in a while loop and searches all topics with that particular tag. and hence can be displayed later as a list with found solutions.