# autocomplete JTextField for netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, autocomplete, jtextfield

I created a desktop application in netbeans ,up to yesterday it was well but now the requirements are changed and client want all JTextField as autocomplete , the source is databse, I googled and tried to find any suitable example for netbeans but i was not able to find such thing so please help me how can I implement auto complete thing in netbeans?
Please help

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219625/how-would-be-implements-autosugesion-in-jtextarea-swing/15220056#15220056) similar answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [auto-complete package](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html)

Comment: this package of swingx but its not available in netbeans i think? or how can i use it

Comment: great , but i am issues here , i am able to open swinglabs.org  due to time out, can u help me by attaching jar file  please

Comment: @Ali please to check for links [great member of SwingX](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:203657+[swingx]), in her profile are a few links to the current version SwingX 1.6.3 ...

Comment: now i get other errors , 1:Netbeans hangs when I add something from swingx , also

Comment: import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator says package not found

Answer (score 2):

- you can use [AutoComplete JComboBox/JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968) based on standard Java5/6 API,
- SwingX has(I tried one two years back) package for pallete in NetBeans
- you can use and combine SwingX packages in/with Swing GUI without any limitations