# Netbeans Platform completion in a custom editor

Tags: netbeans-platform

I'm very new to Netbeans platform and I'm trying to assess whether it is possible to utilize the completion functionality outside of the source editors? I followed the completion tutorial but that merely sets up the completion and registers it as a service. Then the editor picks it up based on the MIME-type.

What I want to do is to write a topcomponent with a jtable in it and enable completion when one edits a cell in the table. Can anyone point me in the right direction on what I need to do?

Regards,
Rickard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rickard

What you may be referring to is an auto-complete textbox. You don't need any netbeans specific code to do this. Look at the links below.

[autocomplete JTextField for netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845250/autocomplete-jtextfield-for-netbeans)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1124992

If you want Java API Lookup for a text field I think you might have to integrate the CodeCompletionProvider with your code and then call  that provider from your textbox Keyboard Event Handler.

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html