# Autocomplete and editable JTextField using AutoCompleteDecorator

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtextfield, swingx

I am using a `JTextField` for auto suggestion, as described in following code

```
String[] myStrings = new String[] {"Elem1","Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

JList list = new JList(myStrings); //data has type Object[]
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(list, this.customerNameField, ObjectToStringConverter.DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION);
```

Now I can only select the name from `myStrings`, but my client want that he can select the value from auto suggestion also he can add other vales but above code is not allowing me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use [AutoComplete JComboBox/JTextField#setStrict(boolean flag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918)
- or search for equivalent in [SwingX#enableAutoCompletion()](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/Configurator.html#enableAutoCompletion%28javax.swing.JList,%20javax.swing.text.JTextComponent%29),

Comment: i am not able Configurator in the swingx

Comment: sorry I found out about that on their official forum, sorry I use standard AutoCompleted