# How to implement auto complete functionality in a cell in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtable, jcombobox

My JTable has a cell editor implemented as an instance of the DefaultCellEditor(JComboBox) class.
I've tried a couple of different things ([Adding Auto-Completion Support to Swing Comboboxes](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/19/adding-auto-completion-to-swing-comboboxes.html)
) but it still doesn't work.

1:

```
//
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combo);
DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(combo);
TableColumn column = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
column.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
//
```

2:

```
//
Object[] elements = new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" };
JComboBox c = new JComboBox(elements);
c.setEditable(true);
AutoCompleteSupport support = AutoCompleteSupport.install(c, GlazedLists.eventListOf(elements));
support.setSelectsTextOnFocusGain(false);
support.setHidesPopupOnFocusLost(false);
support.setStrict(false);
ComboBoxCellEditor combo = new ComboBoxCellEditor(c);
TableColumn column = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
ComboTableCellRenderer renderer = new ComboTableCellRenderer();
column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
column.setCellEditor(combo);
//
```

3:

```
//
Object[] elements = new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" };
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(elements);
comboBox.setEditable(true);
AutoCompletion ac = new AutoCompletion(comboBox);
ac.setStrict(false);
DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);
TableColumn column = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
column.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
//
```

The problem I am facing is that as soon as the user starts typing in the combo box, it comes out of the editing mode, and thus effectively preventing entering any value.

Comment: Did you try the autocomplete from SwingX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no issue with my favorite [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968), still there second choice use `AutoComplete JTextField` instead of `AutoComplete JComboBox`,

[image]

[image]

added to the code from Oracle JTable tutorial

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * TableRenderDemo is just like TableDemo, except that it
 * explicitly initializes column sizes and it uses a combo box
 * as an editor for the Sport column.
 */
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //Set up column sizes.
        initColumnSizes(table);
        //Fiddle with the Sport column's cell editors/renderers.
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    /*
     * This method picks good column sizes.
     * If all column heads are wider than the column's cells'
     * contents, then you can just use column.sizeWidthToFit().
     */
    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(null, column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).getTableCellRendererComponent(table, longValues[i], false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Initializing width of column " + i + ". " + "headerWidth = " + headerWidth + "; cellWidth = " + cellWidth);
            }
            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table, TableColumn sportColumn) {
        //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
        ArrayList<String> listSomeString = new ArrayList<String>();        
        listSomeString.add("Snowboarding");
        listSomeString.add("Rowing");
        listSomeString.add("Knitting");
        listSomeString.add("Speed reading");
        listSomeString.add("Pool");
        listSomeString.add("None of the above");
        Java2sAutoComboBox comboBox = new Java2sAutoComboBox(listSomeString);
        comboBox.setDataList(listSomeString);
        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {{"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true}, {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true}, {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), false}};
        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy", "None of the above", new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                        + " to " + value
                        + " (an instance of "
                        + value.getClass() + ")");
            }

            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println("New value of data:");
                printDebugData();
            }
        }

        private void printDebugData() {
            int numRows = getRowCount();
            int numCols = getColumnCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                    System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
    table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    final JXComboBox editorComboBox = new JXComboBox(array);
    editorComboBox.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
        public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
            //make sure combobox handles key events
            editorComboBox.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
        public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {}
        public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {}
    });
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(editorComboBox);
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    column.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor(editorComboBox));
```