# A component implementing search

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jtextfield

Is it possible to have a JTextField with a drop-down list similar to the implementations of search via different engines?

I'm trying to deliver table column filtration and addition/removal via a such a component.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897839/how-to-implement-auto-complete-functionality-in-a-cell-in-jtable

Answer (score 3):

An editable `JCombobox` has a `JTextField` as editor, so that is very close to  what you want. You can combine this with autocompletion functionality (e.g. by using SwingX which allows to decorate a combobox and making autocompletion a one-liner)

Answer (score 0):

`JComboBox` gives you the `flexibility` of a `TextField and a List`.

Eg:

```
JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();
combo.setEditable(true);
```

`setEditable(true)` will make the JComboList behave editable like textfield.