# How to assign the auto complete text field to JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtable, jtextfield

I have created one `Class` for auto complete text fields.

I want to use that `Class` and try to include my `JTable` cell fields, but it won't display.

Please advice

Answer (score 3):

- you can to use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968)
- put this [JComboBox / JTextField to the JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901944/714968) as [Renderer and Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming I understand the question)

You need to wrap your editor in [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html).  Have a look at [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) an example.

Once you have it set up, you need to register the editor with the table.

One way is to register the editor with the column in question via the [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html)

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(indexToColumnInQuestion).setCellEditor(tableCellAutoCompleteEditor);
```

Comment: actually i created one class called AutoCompletetext for autocompletetext.i try to include that class into my working jtable cellhow it ll possible

Comment: Did you read about `TableCellEditor`?  Did you read "Using Other Editors".  Basically, you will need to wrap you `AutoCompleteText` field in a `TableCellEditor` and register it with the column you want to use the editor on, as said in my answer.

Comment: +1 - despite of the _best ways_: in registering per-table vs. per-column there is no general best, just two paths for different contexts :-)