# The Auto Complete JCombo Box (Java2S) sets wrong value on Change Event

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jtable, jcombobox

With refrence To The [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897839/how-to-implement-auto-complete-functionality-in-a-cell-in-jtable/10901944#10901944)! By abg and answer By mKorBel.

And Using J2s [Auto Complete Combo Box](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm)!

The Code in the Answer By mKorBel For My Case has another problem in the following code when i edit the third row it works fine, but when i click 1st row for edit it sets the value of first row to the selected 3 rd row.

```
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
       {

          JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
          String    itemStr= comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
          int  selectedRowLocal= tblDetailInfoParts.getSelectedRow();

          if (selectedRowLocal != -1) 
          {
             if ((itemStr != null) && (itemStr.compareTo("") != 0) ) 
             {
                tblDetailInfoParts.setValueAt(itemStr, selectedRowLocal, 15);
             }

          }

       }
    });
```

Comment: still no luck in formatting your code properly? Please try harder ... and remember: this forum formatting software doesn't like tabs :-)

Comment: As to your question: why insist in using unmaintained outdated - to the extent of being jurassic - code examples? AutoComplete is not trivial to get right ... so use a modern, well-maintained implementation like f.i. SwingX

Comment: i mentioned int the last question that i tried SwingX but my main Requirement was not fullfilled that when i type the characters the long list is not filtered  and this problem was accpted by mKorbel and he suggested this solution to my problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "filtered"? Anyway, note that if you want to use swingX autocomplete as editing component, you need to use a ComboBoxCellEditor instead of the core.

Comment: @kleopatra basically, as you type, the match is selected in the drop down rather then the list being filter to only show matching results - it's one of the reasons we choice not to use it

Comment: @MadProgrammer ahhh ... true, real filtering is not supported (you might consider filing a featrue request :-) - but neither is it in the old java2s example, as far as I remember.

Comment: @ kleopatra  no it is working in javas example

Comment: I have tested it but has the one bug which ijust mentioned in this question

Comment: @MadProgrammer please give my question upvote as u understand my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead Of Adding the action Listener to comboBox(i.e. added to the JTable), I added [Rob Camick's Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/)! and in the cell which i added comboBox i listened to change that works perfectly for me. (That was pointed in the comment of my previous question on Java2s Autocomplete Combo Box  By **@mKorbel**)

```
 private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) 
 {
    AddingPartsChangeEvent();
 }
```

The Code For My Table Cell Listener To My JTable is as follows

```
   private void addingPartsChangeEvent() 
   {

      Action actionProd = new AbstractAction() 
      {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {
            try 
            {
               boolean newChk = false;
               TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener) e.getSource();
               int selectedRow = tcl.getRow();
               int selectedCol = tcl.getColumn();

               if (selectedCol == 4) 
               {
                  Object partO = tcl.getNewValue();
                  String design = null;
                  String partStr = partO.toString();
                  tblDetailInfoParts.setValueAt(partStr,selectedRow, 15) ;
               }

            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      };
      TableCellListener tclProd = new TableCellListener(tblDetailInfoParts,
      actionProd);
    }
```

Comment: @kleopatra can you tell what is the wrong with this formatting? I have used Camel notation for variable declaration.

Comment: You can now  see that i have formatted code using [here](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/indentation.html)!