# SwingX identifies only listed word from array of words , and won't let other words to get chosen

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, intellisense, swingx

I'm trying to add auto-completion to my current code , so after countless times 
I decided to try `SwingX`.

The code compiles , works ,however I still have some "minor" issues .

Here is my code :

```
public class GuiHandler extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private javax.swing.JTextField jtfBoxOfCurrentPath;


// more irrelevant code 

       private void afterXMLfileWasUploaded() { 

       String[] tab = {"abc", "def", "ghjk", "lmnop", "qrst", "rstuv", "wxyz"};

        JList list = new JList(tab); //data has type Object[]

        // jtfBoxOfCurrentPath.setToolTipText("");  // I removed this line , this is when I don't want to use auto-completion 

        AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(list, jtfBoxOfCurrentPath, ObjectToStringConverter.DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION);

        jtfBoxOfCurrentPath.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                boxOfCurrentPathActionPerformed(evt);
            }

        });

// and more code
```

This is the general view of my program : [image: XML search engine]  . As mentioned by the name of the method `afterXMLfileWasUploaded` , after I hit the `open XML file` button , the file is uploaded and parsed into the program (no problem with that) .

But when I try to write something in the box `Current path` , then :

- I can only write words from the `tab` array above
- I can't write any other word or character that start with a character that is not listed in

  "abc", "def", "ghjk", "lmnop", "qrst", "rstuv", "wxyz"
- I can't actually erase any word that was written using the `tab` array above .

What's wrong then ? any help would be very appreciated

Regards

Answer (score 2):

> I can only write words from the tab array above

- no idea, you have to use current version SwingX 1.6.3
- to check if is backspace fixed (not SwingX expert),
- can help you to check post [great member of SwingX team @kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:203657%20%5Bswingx%5D),
- or on their forum you can searching for relevant infos

> I can't write any other word or character that start with a character that is not listed in

[org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.Configurator#configureTextComponent()](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/Configurator.html#enableAutoCompletion%28javax.swing.JList,%20javax.swing.text.JTextComponent%29), notice API talking about `Document` (`Model` for `JTextComponents`)

---

- my favorite workaround is (without about mentioned issues and potential bugs)  [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968) (Java5 and higher),
- there you can simple to set AutoComplete JComboBox/JTextField`#setStrict(boolean flag)`
- no issue with BackSpace, Focus, to store last Caret

Comment: I've tried your example ,the code doesn't allow to enter anything but the words that were put using `listSomeAnotherString.add(...)`

Comment: again di you tried to switch to the `someTextField.setStrict(false)` ???? or `someComboBox.setStrict(false)` ???, I can't believe :-)

Comment: Okay ,that works :) so big thanks ,first . But, the question is , can I use this class to manipulate the field that I mentioned above , in my program , with the object `JTextField jtfBoxOfCurrentPath` ?

Comment: Okay I almost succeeded to solve the problem . The thing is , that the code recognizes only the first word that I enter. If I continue typing , it doesn't auto-complete anymore . Is it possible to solve this ?