# Java jList add item based on combobox selection

Tags: java, swing, csv, jcombobox, jlist

I have a csv file that is being loaded in my programme. It contains citys and areas and some other stuff (not important here). Once the csv is selected I load the data into several comboboxes.

1 Thing is not working, I have a combobox containing all the citys and now I need to list all the areas for that country based on selection from the combobox.

Here is the event:

```
 private void cboProvinciesItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                               
   //System.out.println(Arrays.asList(gemeentesPerProvincie(gemeentes)));
    invullenListProvincie(gemeentes);
}
```

Here is the method:

```
      private void invullenListProvincie(ArrayList<Gemeentes> gemeentes) {

    Gemeentes gf = (Gemeentes) cboProvincies.getSelectedItem();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(model);

    for (Gemeentes gemeente : gemeentesPerProvincie(gemeentes)) {
        model.addElement(gemeente);
    }

    lstGemeentes.setModel(model);

}
```

and this is the method to filter all the areas that equal the selection from the combobox:

```
    private ArrayList<Gemeentes> gemeentesPerProvincie(ArrayList<Gemeentes> gemeentes) {

    String GemPerProv = (String) cboProvincies.getSelectedItem();
    ArrayList<Gemeentes> selectie = new ArrayList<Gemeentes>();
    for (Gemeentes gemeente : gemeentes) {
        if (gemeente.getsProvincie().equals(GemPerProv)) {
            selectie.add(gemeente);
        }
    }

    return selectie;
}
```

I am convinced the error is the way I am trying to add items to the jList gemeentesPerProvincie(), I have tried so many things already. I really hope someone can see what i am clearly missing...

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong based on bits and pieces of code. If you don't get a strong answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are you registering the `cboProvinciesItemStateChanged` eventhandler with the combobox's state change event?  Also, `gf` and `list` are unused and unneeded

Comment: I understand, but I tought maybe someone might see what I am doing wrong adding the items to the jList. Java is kinda annoying to ask questions about I think. Also the documentation for the jList is always about adding a simple string which is not the case here.

Comment: Yes Attila I register it with the combobox state change event. Would there be a possibility to upload my project somewhere so that people could have a look at it? Is this allowed @ stackoverflow?

Comment: A JList model can and should accept any type of object. The keys are that 1) all objects should be the same type (enforced with generics) and 2) making sure that you display your objects properly. The latter is where a ListCellRenderer comes in handy.

Comment: I have uploaded my project if anyone wants to give it a go, be my hero... http://dgoods.eu/gemeentes.zip

Comment: the correct url... http://dgoods.eu/Gemeentes.zip

Comment: Again, consider simplifying your problem greatly and then posting the compilable and runnable code with a small data file here. It will greatly increase your chances of getting useful help. 1+ to @mKorbel for his useful suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

- use [AutoComplete JComboBox / JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255918/714968) instead of plain [JCombobox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with one Column (maybe without `JTableHeader`)
- create [TableMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)l with two Columns, cities and areas, then both `JComboBox` and `JTable` have got the same data, from `JTable` to remove Column cities (`JTable.removeColumn()` is only about `JTables view`, data are still presents in the `TableModel`)
- add [RowFilter to JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) to the Column contains cities, output to the `JTables view` will be only areas for cities,
- value for `RowFilter` will be became from `JComboBox.getSelectedItem`
- data for `JCombobox` are from `TableModel`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only problem is that I have to do it in a jList. I have a test in a couple of days so the code itself will be checked.

Comment: change JList to the JTable isn't something, somehow very complicated matter

Comment: I have uploaded my project if anyone wants to give it a go, be my hero... http://dgoods.eu/Gemeentes.zip