# getting the selected item string from Java2sAutoComboBox()

Tags: java, autocomplete

I want to get the selected Item from the Java2sAutoComboBox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist)

What can be done?

Also suggest me if there is any other way I could realize an **AutoComplete Feature**
in J2SE.

Comment: have you tries to use swingX library as said in the link that you have mentioned?

Comment: No....!!!! I'm a newbie... Don't know how to use the library....

Comment: And I've already used the Java2sAutoComboBox class file in my program....

Comment: if possible please instruct me on using SwingX as well....!!!!

Comment: did you 1st integrate the library to your project?

Comment: I'm using jdk right now...
And I just read the documentation of SwingX
I didn't found any AutoCompletion feature in JXComboBox


https://swingx.java.net/documentation/

But in the Features article they've said that there is an AutoComplete Feature according to:

http://swingx.java.net/

Comment: Actually you have to tweak some code to get the right thing with the code..

Comment: ok.... wait swingx-beaninfo-1.6.2.jar or swingx-core-1.6.2.jar which of these jar file should I include in my working folder i.e. C:\jdk1.7\bin

Comment: both of them have to be integrated