# Automatic suggestion for JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, search-suggestion

My Java application gives user a textbox to input some String data.Domain size of input is around 500 words. I want to give suggestion when user starts typing a word. Something Like Google Automatic suggestion. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm

When you create an instance of this autocomplete textfield you have to pass your 500 words in there as a list.

Comment: i tried the above code but that just shows the first list value in textbox and user cannot type anything.

Comment: unfortunately I can't check this until monday.

Comment: Worked fine. Here is a example that helped me.Thanks Moh-Aw!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918