# Predictive Text in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list suggestions to when typing inside the text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674462/how-to-list-suggestions-to-when-typing-inside-the-text-field)

Is there any way to get predictive text in JTextField in java swing? Like if i want to get the name of the city from the user, then it should predict the city.

Comment: I think you mean auto-complete, not predictive text...

Comment: This link may help http://www.coderanch.com/t/486422/GUI/java/Auto-Complete-JTextField

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186955/create-a-autocompleting-textbox-in-java-with-a-dropdown-list/14194104#14194104) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwingX provides auto-complete feature: http://swingx.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have an auto complete in some of my programs. Unfortunately I cannot find where I get the info on the internet. I post the code I have, but I am not the "original" writer of this AutoCompleteDocument class. If you find it on the internet give me the link so the credit can be given to the original writer.

```
public class AutoCompleteDocument extends PlainDocument {

    private final List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private final JTextComponent jTextField;

    public AutoCompleteDocument(JTextComponent field, String[] aDictionary) {
        jTextField = field;
        dictionary.addAll(Arrays.asList(aDictionary));
    }

    public void addDictionaryEntry(String item) {
        dictionary.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        String word = autoComplete(getText(0, getLength()));
        if (word != null) {
            super.insertString(offs + str.length(), word, a);
            jTextField.setCaretPosition(offs + str.length());
            jTextField.moveCaretPosition(getLength());
        }
    }

    public String autoComplete(String text) {
        for (Iterator<String> i = dictionary.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String word = i.next();
            if (word.startsWith(text)) {
                return word.substring(text.length());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }  
}
```

then to use it simply initialise it with something like that

```
AutoCompleteDocument autoCompleteDoc;

autoCompleteDoc = new AutoCompleteDocument(aJTextField, anArray);
aJTextField.setDocument(autoCompleteDoc);
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation:

```
public class Predict
{
    private final static String [] COLORS = new String [] {"red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "cyan", "blue", "violet"};

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        final JTextField field = new JTextField ();

        field.getDocument ().addDocumentListener (new DocumentListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate (DocumentEvent e)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate (DocumentEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getOffset () + e.getLength () == e.getDocument ().getLength ())
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run ()
                        {
                            predict (field);
                        }
                    });
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate (DocumentEvent e)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Auto complete");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane ();
        contentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        contentPane.add (field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    private static void predict (JTextField field)
    {
        String text = field.getText ();

        String prediction = null;

        for (String color: COLORS)
        {
            if (color.startsWith (text) && !color.equals (text))
            {
                if (prediction != null) return;

                prediction = color;
            }
        }

        if (prediction != null)
        {
            field.setText (prediction);

            field.setCaretPosition (text.length ());
            field.select (text.length (), prediction.length ());
        }
    }
}
```