# search box in java like the one in web browsers

Tags: java

I have an application where I implemented an `onKeyPressed` event listener for a text field.

In this listener I do a search for results like the input inmy database.

Is there a way that I can show an autocomplete list for the text box displaying the results of the database search?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: There is no question here. What would you like answered?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using swing you can attempt to link the textbox with a list and then you can achive autocomplete functionality using the swing [autocomplete](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/package-summary.html) package.

[Also see this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist) [Or this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674462/how-to-list-suggestions-to-when-typing-inside-the-text-field)